# In ISO 8601, is the timezone applied during the generation of the timestamp, or does the user/program that interprets it need to do it manually?

Tags: date, utc, date-formatting, iso8601

I have an ISO 8601 timestamp: 2010-01-31T22:01:00-05:00. I'm not sure what this timestamp would be when converted to UTC, though. Here's my thinking:

It could mean January 31st at 22:01 UTC, because the -05:00 has already been applied to the timestamp when it was originally generated. However, it could also mean February 1st 03:01 UTC, because the -05:00 must be manually applied by the program/person that interprets the timestamp.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

The date and time indicate the local time in the time zone that has the specified offset.  The timestamp in your example corresponds to February 1st 03:01 UTC.